# Knockout and ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have been told to build a web application using MVC4,Bootstrap and knockout.I am completely new to all three by the way.Please bear with me,as this might be long post.I have 3 pages : A creation page,A listing page and an Editing page.The creation page is working fine,but the listing page is where I am facing loads of problems.The listing page lists all the data.
The first issue that I am facing here is that the deletion of data is happening,but I have to refresh the page to see the deletion update.Secondly,the edit button is not redirecting to the Edit page.I still am the list page itself.

My controller

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        Provider providerList = new Provider();
        DAL DataAccess = new DAL();
        IList<Provider> providers = DataAccess.GetListofProviders();

        int pageSize = 5;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(providers.ToPagedList(pageNumber,pageSize));
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        DAL dataAccess = new DAL();
        Provider provider = dataAccess.GetASingleProvider(id);
        return View(provider);
    } 

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        DAL DataAccess = new DAL();
        DataAccess.DeleteProvider(id);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

My JS Scripts
For Delete and Edit

```
   self.Delete = function (Provider) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this row?')) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Provider/Delete/" + Provider.ProviderID(),
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: ko.toJSON(Provider.ProviderID()),
            success: function (data) {
                self.Providers.remove(Provider);
            }
        }).fail(
             function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
                 alert(err);
             });
    }
}

  self.update = function (Provider) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Provider/Edit/"+ Provider.ProviderID(),
        cache: false,
        type: 'PUT',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: ko.toJSON(Provider),
        success: function (data) {
            //alert(data);
            self.Providers.removeAll();
            self.Providers(data);
            self.Provider(null);
           }
       })
   .fail(
       function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
          alert(err);
      };
   }
```

Edit Page

```
<head>
<title>EDIT PROVIDER</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">    
    <h1 class="col-sm-offset-2">Edit Provider Details:</h1><br />
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="ProviderDetailsForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">FIRST NAME:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Enter the First Name" id="FirstName" data-bind="value:FirstName" onkeypress="return onlyAlphabets(event);">
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-4 labelfont errorMsg" id="Err_FirstName">Enter the first name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">CERTIFICATION:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="form-control" id="Certification" data-bind="value:SelectedCertification,options:Certification, optionsCaption: 'Select a Certification'">
                </select>
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-4 labelfont errorMsg" id="Err_Certification">Choose a Certificaton</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">SPECIALIZATION:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="form-control" id="Specialization" data-bind="value:Specialization">
                    <option>Select a Specialization</option>    
                </select>
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-4 labelfont errorMsg" id="Err_Specialization">Choose a Specialization</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">TAXONOMY CODE:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Taxonomy code" id="TaxonomyCode" data-bind="textInput:TaxonomyCode,valueUpdate:'blur'">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="button" id="Update" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-4">Update</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/Create_Script.js"></script>
```

The Provider View Model.

```
      var Provider =
          {
              ProviderID: ko.observable(""),
              FirstName: ko.observable(""),
              LastName: ko.observable(""),
              Certification: ko.observableArray(["M.B.B.S", "M.D.", "R.N.", "M.S.N."]),
              SelectedCertification: ko.observable(""),
              Specialization: ko.observable(""),
              TaxonomyCode:ko.observable(""),
              SSN: ko.observable(""),
              ContactNumber: ko.observable(""),
              ContactEmail: ko.observable(""),
              FacilityName: ko.observable(""),
          }
             ko.applyBindings(Provider);
```

Sorry about the long post folks.But,I searched a lot about this issue on Stackoverflow as well as other sites and was not able to find a proper answer.Please guide a newbie here.Thanks a lot.

Edited to add the HTML for the list page.

```
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@model IPagedList<DEMO_JAN14.Models.Provider>
<head>
    <title>LIST OF PROVIDERS</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
       <h1>Providers List</h1><br/>
          <a class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1" href="/Provider/Create">Create</a><br/>
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="tblData">
       <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Certification</th>
        <th>Specialization</th>
        <th>Taxonomy Code</th>
        <th>SSN</th>
        <th>Facility Name</th>
        <th>Contact No</th>
        <th>Contact Email</th>  
    </tr>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:viewModel.DataList">
        <tr>
            <td class="col-lg-2" data-bind="text: FirstName"></td>
            <td class="col-lg-2" data-bind="text: LastName"></td>
            <td class="col-lg-2" data-bind="text: Certification"></td>
            <td class="col-lg-2" data-bind="text: Specialization"></td>
            <td class="col-lg-2" data-bind="text: TaxonomyCode"></td>
            <td class="col-lg-2" data-bind="text: SSN"></td>
            <td class="col-lg-2" data-bind="text: FacilityName"></td>
            <td class="col-lg-2" data-bind="text: ContactNumber"></td>
            <td class="col-lg-2" data-bind="text: ContactEmail"></td>
            <td><button type="button" id="Edit" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click:$root.update">Edit</button></td>
            <td><button type="button" id="Delete" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click:$root.Delete">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
    Page @(Model.PageCount<Model.PageNumber? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
    @Html.PagedListPager( Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page   }) )
  </div>   
  </body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
</script>
```

Comment: Without posting the code for the manage page it's difficult to answer the question. I'm not sure why you posted the edit page html when the delete and edit link is not working which would both be on the manage page.

Comment: Since the Edit button is linked to the Edit page and knockout binding has to happen on this page,I thought to post the Edit page.I will edit and add the list HTML as well.

Comment: Edit should be changing the location using window.location.href instead of performing an ajax request. Your foreach on the manage page is looping through viewModel.DataList but you are removing an item from providers. Why is a different list being used

Comment: I did that while tinkering with the delete action.The delete was not working when I was using Provider viewmodel.Hence I used the Datalist to get the delete to happen.To be honest,I have no idea of Wndow.location.href as I am very new to knockout and Web programming in general.

Answer (score 0):

the first issue that you faced (delete) you have to set the provider as an observableArray like this:

```
  self.Provider =ko.observableArray(
      {
          ProviderID: ko.observable(""),
          FirstName: ko.observable(""),
          LastName: ko.observable(""),
          Certification: ko.observableArray(["M.B.B.S", "M.D.", "R.N.", "M.S.N."]),
          SelectedCertification: ko.observable(""),
          Specialization: ko.observable(""),
          TaxonomyCode:ko.observable(""),
          SSN: ko.observable(""),
          ContactNumber: ko.observable(""),
          ContactEmail: ko.observable(""),
          FacilityName: ko.observable(""),
      })
```

and about the second problem try to put async option to false in the ajax call and if it doesn't work try to redirect to that page using javascript

Comment: Actually,I did not add this portion of the code,I already have " self.Provider = ko.observable();
    self.Providers = ko.observableArray();."Also,I added the async:false.The redirect to Index action is happening but I dont see the refreshed page with the deleted row.Even though the record is deleted from the database where the record is no longer present.

Comment: Actually I got the Delete to work.Thanks for the suggestion to redirect using Javascript.Could you please help with the second issue.The edit button is not redirecting to the Edit page and How to populate the fields using knockout.many thanks for your help so far.